# PHPUnit - mock callback function

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit, zend-db

Here is a function which uses Zend DB / Tablegateway :

```
public function listAttestations($sSidx = null, $sSord = null, $iOffset = 0, $iLimit = 0)
{
    try {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(
            function (Select $select) use ($sSidx, $sSord, $iOffset, $iLimit) {
                if ($sSidx != null && $sSord != null) {
                    $select->order($sSidx.' '.$sSord);
                }
                $select->join(
                    'f_travclient',
                    'syndic_client_id = f_travclient.travClient_id',
                     array('syndic' => 'nom')
                );
                $select->offset($iOffset);
                $select->limit($iLimit);
            }
        );
        return $resultSet;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e);
    }
}
```

I use PHPUnit to do unit tests. Perhaps, I don't know how to make the function which crosses my previous method. I thought this could be functional :

```
public function testListAttestations()
{
    $resultSet = new ResultSet();

    $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array('select'), array(), '', false);

    $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
            ->method('select')
            ->with()
            ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));

    $attestTable = new FMaiAttestationTable($mockTableGateway, $this->adapter, $this->sql);

    $this->assertSame($resultSet, $attestTable->listAttestations('maiAttestation_id', 'ASC', 0, 30));
}
```

But this doesn't go further the  :

```
function (Select $select) use ($sSidx, $sSord, $iOffset, $iLimit) {
```

Could somebody help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch and use any arguments given to a mocked method with `returnCallback()`:

```
$mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
        ->method('select')
        ->with()
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function($function) use ($resultSet) {
            // do something with the function, for example:
            if(!is_callable($function)) {
                return NULL;
            }
            call_user_func($function, new Select());
            return $resultSet;
        }));
```

Still, you might want to reconsider your current code as it is not necessary to write it nested like this. You could, for example, get an instance of `Select` yourself and use it with `selectWith()`

```
public function listAttestations($sSidx = null, $sSord = null, $iOffset = 0, $iLimit = 0)
{
    try {
        $select = new Select();
        if ($sSidx != null && $sSord != null) {
            $select->order($sSidx.' '.$sSord);
        }
        $select->join(
            'f_travclient',
            'syndic_client_id = f_travclient.travClient_id',
            array('syndic' => 'nom')
        );
        $select->offset($iOffset);
        $select->limit($iLimit);
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        return $resultSet;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e);
    }
}
```

In this case it is now possible to test if your method puts the `Select` together the way you want. You can simply create another `Select` object in your test the way you expect it to be:

```
    $resultSet = new ResultSet();

    $sSidx = 'maiAttestation_id';
    $sSord = 'ASC';
    $iOffset = 0;
    $iLimit = 30;

    $select = new Select();
    $select->order($sSidx.' '.$sSord);
    $select->join(
        'f_travclient',
        'syndic_client_id = f_travclient.travClient_id',
        array('syndic' => 'nom')
    );
    $select->offset($iOffset);
    $select->limit($iLimit);

    $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway',
        array('selectWith'), array(), '', false);

    $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
        ->method('selectWith')
        ->with($select)
        ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));

    $attestTable = new FMaiAttestationTable($mockTableGateway, $this->adapter, $this->sql);

    $this->assertEquals($resultSet, $attestTable->listAttestations($sSidx, $sSord, $iOffset, $iLimit));
```

If the `Select` object used by the mocked method `selectWith` looks any different from the one you created, PHPUnit will throw an error in your test.

Comment: Thanks ! It goes into my method now :)